# Sonido random de lista

Tags: c++

1. Sale no puedo convertir string en const char

   ```
   #include <iostream>
   #include <cstdlib>
   #include <ctime>
   #include <string>
   #include <windows.h>
   #include "MMSystem.h"

   using namespace std;

   int main(int argc, char** argv) 
   {

       srand(time(0));
       string ra[] = {"demon_0.wav","demon_1.wav","jocker.wav"};

       for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++){
           int random = rand() % 3;
           //cout << ra[random] << endl;
           PlaySound(TEXT(ra[random]),NULL,SND_FILENAME|SND_ASYNC);
           system("pause");
       }
       return 0;
   }
   ```

Comment: Por favor traduce la pregunta, estás en Stack Overflow en Español http://es.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: No se si a tu función `playsound` se le ingresa un `char*` pero si es así, en el primer parámetro quita la función `TEXT();` y deja el parámetro como `PlaySound(ra[random][0],NULL,SND_FILENAME|SND_ASYNC);` saludos..

Answer (score 2):

La función `PlaySound` recibe como primer parámetro un `LPCTSTR`

```
BOOL PlaySound(
   LPCTSTR pszSound,
   HMODULE hmod,
   DWORD   fdwSound
);
```

Al definir tu array como `string`, debes utilizar la función `c_str()` para entregar a la función `PlaySound` un puntero a `char`.

Te pongo un ejemplo de lo que tendrías que hacer.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void f( const char *wav )
{
    printf( "%s", wav );
}

int main() 
{

    string ra[] = {"demon_0.wav","demon_1.wav","jocker.wav"};

    f( ra[1].c_str() );

    return 0;
}
```

En tu código, bastaría con hacer:

```
PlaySound(ra[random].c_str(),NULL,SND_FILENAME|SND_ASYNC);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias me sirvió demasiado.